# Mapping with automapper system.strin to string exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have 2 classes .

first class is

```
 public class Client : BaseEntity
    {
        public Client()
            {
        ReportingPeriods = new List<ReportingPeriod>();
        UserAccesses = new List<UserClientAccess>();
        GraphColours = new List<GraphColour>();
        RangeColours = new List<RangeColour>();
        Properties = new List<PropertyMaster>();
        PropertyCustomFilterHeaderMasters = new List<PropertyCustomFilterHeaderMaster>();
        InterestCustomFilterHeaderMasters = new List<InterestCustomFilterHeaderMaster>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        CustomDashboards = new List<CustomDashboard>();
        Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IgnoreComparing]
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Logo Name")]
    public string LogoName { get; set; }

    public ClientStatus Status { get; set; }

    [IgnoreComparing]
    public virtual ICollection<ReportingPeriod> ReportingPeriods { get; set; }
    [IgnoreComparing]
    public virtual ICollection<UserClientAccess> UserAccesses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PropertyCustomFilterHeaderMaster> PropertyCustomFilterHeaderMasters { get; set; }
    [IgnoreComparing]
    public virtual ICollection<InterestCustomFilterHeaderMaster> InterestCustomFilterHeaderMasters { get; set; }
    [IgnoreComparing]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and the second class is clientDto

```
 public class ClientDto : IdModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AreaUnit { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }      
}
```

Can i map this two classes with automapper with this way

```
cfg.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
```

I'm trying to create mapping, everything works fine but app throws exception

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Here is the linq query

```
public async Task<PagedResultOutput<ClientDto>> GetClients(GetClientsInput input) 
{ 
    var clients = Queryable().AsNoTracking(); 
    var totalCount = await clients.CountAsync(); 
    clients = clients.OrderBy(input.Sorting)
                     .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                     .Take(in‌​put.MaxResultCount); 
     return new PagedResultOutput<ClientDto>(totalCount, await clients.ProjectToListAsync<ClientDto>(_mapperConfiguration))‌​; 
}
```

Comment: I think exception has something to do with you LINQ query not mapping

Comment: my linq query is 

 public async Task<PagedResultOutput<ClientDto>> GetClients(GetClientsInput input)
        {
            var clients = Queryable().AsNoTracking();

            var totalCount = await clients.CountAsync();
            clients = clients.OrderBy(input.Sorting).Skip(input.SkipCount).Take(input.MaxResultCount);

            return new PagedResultOutput<ClientDto>(totalCount, await clients.ProjectToListAsync<ClientDto>(_mapperConfiguration));
        }

Comment: rather than await clients.ProjectToListAsync<ClientDto>(_mapperConfiguration))‌​;, what happens if you simplify to clients.Select(c=>c.Name);  ?

The way I read your map, only the Name property would get mapped, but both your dto and your entity inherits off other classes... Maybe you can chop off the irrelevant bits and only post the bare minimum that still triggers the error?

Comment: I don't see `AreaUnit` and `Currency` in `Client`. Is your code complete?